# Bulk theme settings in wordpress multisite

Tags: multisite, options

I have a multisite with 500+ subsites.

I would like to install the same theme in all 500+ sites. Most of them requires configuration like selecting sidebar(left/right), Selecting primary menu etc.

Is there any plugin available to do this job?
OR
Can anyone give me some idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you configure your Theme settings code properly, the Theme will work fine without having any user-defined settings.

The key is to define a defaults array, and anytime you need to output a Theme option, run an `array_merge()` on the defaults array, and the theme's options DB entry. Something like this:

```
<?php
global $mytheme_options;
$mytheme_options = mytheme_get_options();

function mytheme_get_options() {
    // Defaults array, defined elsewhere
    $option_defaults = mytheme_get_option_defaults();
    // Return parsed args
    $options = wp_parse_args( get_option( 'theme_mytheme_options', array() ), $option_defaults );
}
?>
```

Then you only ever use the globalized `$mytheme_options`, which will always contain either the default option, or the user-defined option, if defined.